# How to dynamically add class in Handlebars template

Tags: javascript, html, handlebars.js, html-templates

I am trying to either dynamically create HTML elements in my Handlebars template, specifically:

```
<span class="fa fa-star checked"></span>
```

Or I want to be able to select existing elements and add the 'checked' class to them. It's for a star rating display, if a book has a rating of 5, then I want 5 out of 5 spans to have the checked class and styled appropriately.

So far I've tried using jQuery to target the span elements and add a class ie. `$('#star-1').addClass('checked');` But I get a null value when searching for that element.

I've also tried to append child elements to a parent div with a for loop, but I get a similar problem with not being able to find and select the parent container. The closest I've got is shown below with returning a single span element in a for loop or returning 5 span elements without the class. Any help would be appreciated.

In my template.html file:

```
<div class="rating-container">
    {{#renderStars rating}}
    <span class="fa fa-star" id="star-1"></span>
    <span class="fa fa-star" id="star-2"></span>
    <span class="fa fa-star" id="star-3"></span>
    <span class="fa fa-star" id="star-4"></span>
    <span class="fa fa-star" id="star-5"></span>
    {{/renderStars}}
</div>
```

Then in my app.js file:

```
Handlebars.registerHelper('renderStars', (rating) => {
  for (let i = 0; i <= rating - 1; i++) {
    return new Handlebars.SafeString("<span class='fa fa-star checked'></span>");
  };
});
```

Finally a snippet of the context JSON data being passed to Handlebars template:

```
[
  {
    "month": "January",
    "image": "/images/sapiens.jpg",
    "altText": "Sapiens: A Brief History of Humankind, book by Yuval Noah Harari",
    "title": "Sapiens: A Brief History of Humankind",
    "author": "Yuval Noah Harari",
    "rating": 5,
},
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*"I've tried using jQuery [...] But I get a null value when searching for that element."*

You need to wait until the stars are appended to the DOM, before doing that.

Regarding your `for` loop, it will only execute one iteration, since you `return` (end the function) during the first iteration.

You could try this:

```
Handlebars.registerHelper('renderStars', (rating) => {
  let result = '';
  for (let i = 1; i <= 5; i++) {
    let checked = rating >= i ? ' checked' : '';
    result += `<span class='fa fa-star${checked}'></span>`;
  }
  return new Handlebars.SafeString(result);
});
```